# How to set buffer and download cache in local to play offline from .PLS file in AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, http-live-streaming

AVPlayer is playing .pls file perfectly but now need to extend support with offline cache and play them offline. I want to set Buffer Values like (200KB, 500KB, 1MB) to download streaming cache in local iOS directory and play them offline.

Code for Playing:

```
myplayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url as! URL)
myPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: myplayerItem)
myPlayer.play();
```

Please Note: This .pls file contain only audio data and no video data. While open the pls file in text editor it looks like below:

```
[playlist]
numberofentries=1
File1=http://server.com:8085/stream
Title1=somename
Length1=-1
version=2
```

Please share your experience for above. is it possible in iOS or not?